# google app engine taskqueues

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Have some problems using taskqueues in google app engine. I tried doing the same as in this site:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push

But it seems like my task is never executed, I get this error:

WARNING  2012-11-25 15:29:21,258 taskqueue_stub.py:1978] Task task1 failed to execute. This task will retry in 12.800 seconds

The code is mainly the same except of these:

```
class CounterWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def init(self): # should run at most 1/s
    def txn():
      logging.info("bla")
    db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

and I just add the task like this:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/worker')
```

What I really want is just running a block of code that dont timeouts. So I read I could use taskqueues. But I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to execute tasks "vanilla" then have a look at the deferred functions.

[Background work with the deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred)

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

  def do_something_expensive(a, b, c=None):
      logging.info("Doing something expensive!")
      # Do your work here

  # Somewhere else
  deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, c=True)
```

You won't need a url/webapp handler as you can pass the function directly.

Comment: Woops, wrong place to comment. Marked your answer as the solution :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Now I get PicklingError: Can't pickle <type '_sre.SRE_Pattern'>: it's not found as _sre.SRE_Pattern when I want to call a function in my MainHandler when it's done :(

Comment: I'd guess that's because that handler is long gone by the time the task returns. If you just need a handler that can run forever, if needed, have you looked at backends? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

Comment: Yeah I have looked at it, but I really think its overkill to use it. I find it quite surprising to be so difficult just to run a block of code without timing out.

Comment: It's not so bad really, and they come in very handy for other reasons as well like persisting state for as long as needed.

Answer (score 5):

By default, task queues send a POST request to whatever handler is mapped to the URL (in your case /worker, which should be mapped to CounterWorker). Therefore you need to define a post method in your CounterWorker method.

```
class CounterWorker(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    def txn():
      logging.info("bla")
    db.run_in_transaction(txn)
```

Your comment suggests that tasks should just run 1/s. You can define this in your [queue.yaml config file](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Defining_Push_Queues_and_Processing_Rates).

Also, taskqueues have 10 minute timeout, so they wont run forever. To rectify this, try chaining them or use the [deferred API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred). For long running processes, the [backends API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview) is probably a better fit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the other one was the main solution. I upvoted you :)